# While loop with string comparison doesn't work correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, fabric

I have to write part of the program for removing virtual machines from kvm. This is written with fabric for python http://www.fabfile.org/ . So, I need to connect to kvm host, check if vm is running, turn it off and remove.

The issue appeared when I tried to put while loop which contains if statement. It seems to not working properly and even if the machine state is "shut", the program doesn't go further, just repeat up to 5 times same if statement.

I tried different types of string comparison, like:
- if "shut" not in
- == "shut"
- != "shut"
- I tried also put "shut" as a variable

It will be run by Jenkins job and what I can see with this code is just while loop and when it counts up to 5 just go further.

```
running
Domain test-test01.test is being shutdown

running
shut
shut
shut
shut
>>> VM not found on this host, but this is fine 33333
```

This is a code which seems to be ok but doesn't work. `Connection` is just one of the fabric features and works fine. It works as a connection via ssh to some hosts. You can see above what replies I get in the terminal with below code.

```
removed = False
    if vmhosttype == "KVM":
        with Connection(vmhostname) as c:
            if c.sudo("virsh list --all | grep {0}".format(shortfqdn), warn=True, hide="stdout").failed:
                print(">>> VM not found on {0}.".format(vmhostname))
            else:
                print(">>> VM found on {0}.".format(vmhostname))
                if c.sudo("virsh list --all | grep {0} | awk '{{ print $3 }}'".format(shortfqdn)) == "shut":
                    c.sudo("virsh undefine {0} --remove-all-storage".format(shortfqdn), hide=hide)
                    removed = True
                else:
                    c.sudo("virsh shutdown {0}".format(shortfqdn), hide=hide)
                    i = 0
                    while (i < 5):
                        if c.sudo("virsh list --all | grep {0} | awk '{{ print $3 }}'".format(shortfqdn)) != "shut":
                            time.sleep(30)
                            i += 1
                        else:
                            c.sudo("virsh undefine {0} --remove-all-storage".format(shortfqdn), hide=hide)
                            removed = True
                            i = 5
```

Comment: not a [mcve] .. what is `Connection` - your print output does not resemble anything in your code etc. Difficult to help that way.

Comment: `Connection` is fabric built-in feature to connect via ssh to remote hosts. docs.fabfile.org/en/2.4/api/connection.html

I'm pretty sure that it doesn't matter in this case. Connection to the host works fine and without any issues.

Comment: "I'm pretty sure that it doesn't matter in this case.". Very likely you are right. Please edit your Q so we don't have to install `Connection` to understand the problem. Please (re)read the MCVE link provided above. I don't think `bash` is the problem here. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in `stdout` which was empty.